# how to redirect to 404 page if page dynamic page is empty

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I'm having some issue figuring out how I can accomplish a 404 redirect if the does not exist from a dynamic page.

I'm retrieving articles from MySQL, on the article.php I have the following to retrieve the information for the page.

```
if(isset($_GET['article_uid']))
{
    $information        = $articleClass->retrieveArticleInfo();

    $article_title  = $information['article_title'];
    $article_image  = $information['article_image'];
    $article_content    = $information['article_content'];
    $article_image_alt  = $information['article_image_alt'];
    $article_quote      = $information['article_quote'];
}
```

The URL looks like this www.site.com/article/id/title-goes-here,
The issue that I am having is that I'd like to show a 404 page if the page does not exist, the issue is that google has index pages that I have deleted from MySQL and yet if I try to enter that page, it'll show the article.php page but it'll be empty and won't retrieve data from MySQL, but the issue is that it still allows someone to enter that page even if it's empty.

How do I add a redirect to my 404 page, I know the following works if I enter something as like this.. www.site.com/ramdom-letters, it'll take me to www.site.com/404.php but if I'm on any other page such as www.site.com/article/ it will not send the user to the 404.php

```
if(isset($_GET['article_uid']))
{
    $information        = $articleClass->retrieveArticleInfo();

    $article_title      = $information['article_title'];
    $article_image      = $information['article_image'];
    $article_content    = $information['article_content'];
    $article_image_alt  = $information['article_image_alt'];
    $article_quote      = $information['article_quote'];
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.site.com/404/');
}
```

I am using the following code on htaccess to change my urls to a be friendly for seo.
`RewriteRule (?:^|/)article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`

`ErrorDocument 404 http://www.site.com/404.php`

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you make up your own dynamic 404 page (or article) and save it in MySQL. Then when a page is requested check if it exists. If it doesn't, then grab the dynamic 404 page (or article)from MySQL and show that instead, sending a HTTP 404 header also (for the bots/crawlers).

`header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');`

I'd recommend against redirecting to a 404 page if possible.

`header('Location: 404.html');`

Answer (score 0):

You can using php sending a 404 header and then redirect to the 404 page like this

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header('Location: http://www.site.com/404.php');
```

Comment: This has the effect of reporting HTTP 404, followed by a HTTP 301 or 302 immediately after. Wouldn't this be less than ideal?